# Prevent query insertion when there is no data to be inserted

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I'm working with C# and SQL Server CE, My questions are:

1. In my WinForms app, I have several text boxes to be filled with data. I wonder to know how to prevent a user error in case of insertion when there is no text boxes filled?
2. How to determine when there are no data in the text boxes for query insertion?

Here is my code:

```
koneksi.Open();
int query = perintahsql.ExecuteNonQuery();
try
{
    if (query > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Success.");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Can't insert record because of empty(s) field.");
        perintahsql.Cancel();
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Can't insert record!");
    perintahsql.Parameters.Clear();
}
koneksi.Close();
```

Comment: can you check you get `query` return value is `> 0` ? you can check before insert textboxs have value or nor

Answer (score 0):

You need a validation method for your Textfields which you run before idserting the data in the Database, therefor you hvae more approaches depending on your needs. For example:

[Control Validation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2608/C-Validating-TextBox-Control)

[writing your own validating routine](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4840/validation-function-code-review)

Using [validation libraries](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22242/Validation-Library-using-C-3-0-Lambda-Expressions)

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution if it fits with you.

```
private bool ReadyToInsert()
{
    bool isOk = true;
    TextBox[] arrText = new TextBox[] { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3 };

    foreach (TextBox i in arrText)
    {
        if (i.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
        {
            isOk = false;
        }
    }
    return isOk;
}
```

This is a function that checks all textboxes in your form. Call this function before you try to insert the record.

Usage: *something like this*

```
// other codes here
if (ReadyToInsert)
{
    // call insert method here
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Can't insert record because of empty(s) field.");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've try your code but it still showing the primary key that set to be auto increment, do you have any idea?

Comment: what `primary key`? you didn't specify that on the question until now. What error are you getting now @RadityaKurnianto?

Comment: Well actually I have several text boxes and also combo boxes, user need to fill those control, but when I try to leave it blanks, the primary key value that I set to be auto increment always successfully inserted on the query.